# ASP.NET MVC: CS1061 Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Currently I am studying C# ASP.NET MVC and was trying to populate a dropdown based on the past year (2008-2017). Upon following some guide online for dropdown, I encountered this error:

> Compilation Error: "The error is "CS1061: Does not contain a definition for 'Year' and no extension method 'Year' accepting a first argument of type could be found'."

I am completely clueless about this error. I am not even sure if this is because of the dropdown or not. See below for my Code

YearViewModel.cs

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Year")]
public int Year{ get; set; }
```

YearController.cs

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<int> last10Years = new List<int>();
    int currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
    for (int i = currentYear - 10; i < currentYear; i++)
    {
        last10Years.Add(i);
    }
    ViewBag.LastTenYears = new SelectList(last10Years);
    return View();
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Practice.Models.YearViewModel>
<div>
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Year)</dt>
        <dd>@Html.DropDownList("Last Ten Years", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.LastTenYears, "Select A Year")</dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

The error is highlighted in this area

```
<dt>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Year)</dt>
```

Note: I did try to find solution online, and it was not successful

Comment: The model is an `IEnumerable` not a `YearViewModel` you'll need one element from the collection to reference the `Year` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty easy fix:

```
@model YearViewModel
<div>
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Year)</dt>
        <dd>@Html.DropDownList("Last Ten Years", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.LastTenYears, "Select A Year")</dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

The View doesn't return nor work with a collection of `YearViewModel`. It does *receive* one, through the `ViewBag`, but that's another story.